# How to use text formatting for code blocks (1 word only) in medium

Tags: code-formatting, medium.com-publishing-api

I'm trying to write a blog post on medium and format just one word as code like `this` but for some reason I cannot do it by just placing the backtick (`). I'm using an AZERTY keyboard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> on selected text (or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> on Mac)

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this very same issue and found @Stofke's answer formatted an entire paragraph as code.

I then tried to use backticks (i.e. `) and found that wrapping an already written word in them wouldn't work. To my surprise, if you write a single backtick and then type the word you'd want to be highlighted as code right after it gets automatically formatted as one would expect.

This might be a change in Medium's editor, but I thought it was something worth sharing.

Thanks for your input too!